# Access Centos7 server through windows network for Nagios

Tags: linux, windows, centos, remote-desktop

We have a windows network setup at work. A new server was spun up that has Centos 7 on it for us to install Nagios to monitor some services. I need to be able to access the Centos server from a windows machine preferably with a UI.

Did figure out that Centos 7 has a built in Remote desktop, I enabled that and still didn't get the remote connection from Windows to work via the IP address given.

I did download putty.exe and was able to access it, but doing things through the command line is not ideal because I still need to see the dashboards from Nagios.

Reading through the 'Linux In a Windows Network with SAMBA' information did not seem to be what I needed and hadn't been able to find anything relevant that I could use.

Not sure what the best way to go about getting this done...securely...is.

Comment: nagios dashboards are available off the box and have at least basic authentication. So putty and a web browser should suffice

Comment: You need about 3 days with a book on Linux and Nagios.  If you're expecting to do things in GUI format, you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I need to be able to see the dashboard monitoring portion. Yes,it's available out of the box, but being able to pull up the machine after it is setup is still a necessity. The server is part of the hyper-v setup affiliated with the IT department. Accessing it thru the web browser would suffice, but when i put the IP address in, it did not connect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the following:

1. If you enabled remote desktop in CentOS, and it does not work, try to find why. If you will still have problems with it, just edit your question and write what have you done to debug it, and what is exactly your problem.
   Maybe, your CentOS does not even have any desktop environment (GUI).
2. Besides that, you can try RDP alternatives instead (like VNC).
3. Nagios dashboard should be accessible via a web browser, so you can use the web browser of your Windows machine (and not X/GUI in the CentOS). putty + web browser access should be enough for all you need.
4. If you want to work with Linux, the better way is to learn how to do it from console. Otherwise, you will always have problems with incomplete GUI for different settings, that do not support all available options.

Comment: The RDP app is built in, and I was able to pull it up, so yes, CENTOS does have RDP already on it. I followed the instructions online for how to setup the RDP to be accessed from windows, used the IP address that CENTOS gave to use, and still got the "Remote Desktop can't connect" error message. None of the setting changes I made fixed the issue. Could not find any other issues on this or any other information on how to set this up, which is why I posted the original question.

Comment: I do not think that xrdp is preinstalled in CentOS. Are you 100% sure it is an RDP app? Execute "netstat -tulpn" in console to see if some process listens to RDP port (3389) on CentOS machine.

Comment: However, as Drifter104 and me already wrote, you probably do not need to connect to the Desktop of CentOS at all. Try to find out why Nagios is not accessible using console.

Comment: this is a brand new setup. I do not have Nagios installed. I was just giving the reason for the need because I know most just use the cmd line when working with linux. Right now the only way to access the server i'm trying to setup is through the SCVMM server. In the process of trying to setup tigervnc instead, but running into other issues here and there.

Comment: I just found out that the i "running a system based OS where traditional init scripts have been replaced by native systemd services files." I was not the one to do the initial install of linux.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across similar things when I first started using CentOS 7. What's likely happening is the installation of firewalld is causing you grief.

Try running (as root):

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Then try making your connection again. If that works, and you are satisfied with having unrestricted access to your server, run:

```
yum erase firewalld
```

To permanently remove it. If not, I would recommend reading up on using Firewalld and iptables to learn and understand how to tune and configure the firewall.

Comment: command not found. I just found out that the i "running a system based OS where traditional init scripts have been replaced by native systemd services files." I was not the one to do the initial install of linux.

Comment: systemctl is systemd stuff. Instead, as root, run iptables -L -t nat
If you get a bunch of stuff, then this is firewalld talking. If systemctl is not working, then systemd is not enabled correctly. Instead try running
iptables -F -t nat
and
iptables -F